# Convert 3D array image into 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to import an image by `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image`.My image is hand written digit that I wrote on a paper and then I took a picture from it by mobile and then changed its size to 28*28:

[image: Hand written digit 7]

I used the following code :

```
img_width, img_height = 28, 28
img = image.load_img('rgb_seven.jpeg', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)
img_tensor.shape
```

The shape result is:

```
(28, 28, 3)
```

Seems the image is loaded as a **3D array**. I need a **2D array**, so I do :

```
x_image = img_tensor.reshape(len(img_tensor),-1)
x_image.shape
```

result is:

```
(28, 84)
```

Why **84**? I need 28 because I want to flat this to insert as input layer.

What is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load image using `color_mode='grayscale'`

```
img = image.load_img('rgb_seven.jpeg', color_mode='grayscale', target_size=(img_width, img_height))
```

It will give you shape `(28, 28, 1)`

Then using `x_image = img_tensor.reshape(28, 28)` will give you shape `(28, 28)`

The reason you get shape `(28, 84)` is because the `reshape()` will not drop the dimension, so if you want using `img_tensor.reshape(28,-1)` to reshape array with the `(28, 28, 3)` it will return an array as combine the last two dimensions thus you get shape `(28, 28 * 3)`

Comment: do you know,  Why my model that has 99% accuracy, my 8 digit image predicted as 3 pasteboard.co/JKdyUF4.png @Mr.ForExample

Comment: @sayreskabir How did you training the model? Did your dataset pairs the images with right labels? Unfortunately I don't think the information in that screenshot is enough to debug the problem, you may consider to open a new question with your code if you can't find the answer

Comment: I am new on deep learning. This is all my codes https://drive.google.com/file/d/1em5WDygYf1st914EZgcbL_buQ4bPkYjn/view?usp=sharing @Mr.ForExample

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use `tf.squeeze` rather than `reshape`. Tensorflow made a function specifically to remove a specified dimension, and therefore I believe it's preferable to use this one.

```
img = image.load_img('rgb_seven.jpeg',
                     color_mode='grayscale',
                     target_size=(img_width, img_height))
img_tensor = image.img_to_array(img)

img_tensor = tf.squeeze(img_tensor, axis=-1)
```

Comment: While I agree on `squeeze` vs `reshape`, espcially in that case, I think that answer would have deserved to be a comment on @Mr. For Example answer.

Comment: Thanks but I wondered Why my model that has 99% accuracy, my 8 digit image predicted as 3 https://pasteboard.co/JKdyUF4.png @Lescurel